# How to fix "warning: ignoring ref with broken name" in git?

Tags: git

I'm working on OSX. In a particular repo, whenever I tab to autocomplete after typing a git command:

```
$ git diff [clicks tab...]
```

I now see a huge number of warnings:

```
warning: ignoring ref with broken name refs/Icon
warning: ignoring ref with broken name refs/heads/Icon
warning: ignoring ref with broken name refs/remotes/Icon
warning: ignoring ref with broken name refs/remotes/origin/Icon
warning: ignoring ref with broken name refs/tags/Icon
```

It's really annoying, and it means that I can't see the filenames I want to see.

How can I remove or suppress these warnings?

I have an entry for `Icon?` in my `gitignore` file. There is an `Icon?` file in the local directory.

For all the trigger-happy people about to click "duplicate": I've searched for other answers, I [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894135/removing-broken-names-in-git-dropbox-conflicted-copy) but I'm not sure how it relates to my situation. It may be that the underlying cause is the same, but it would benefit me and others to have an explanation of how to fix this problem.

Comment: I wonder if this is a result of OSX case-insensitive file system.  Do you have a conflict between Icon/icon ? You could try `git update-ref -d <ref>` to nuke one of them

Comment: You don't have the same problem (which is interesting), but the solution in the linked question is the same:  delete the offending files carefully, after backing up your repo.

Answer (score 12):

The `Icon\r` file is created by Mac OS when you [change a folder's icon](https://superuser.com/questions/298785/icon-file-on-os-x-desktop).

> How can I remove or suppress these warnings?

You need to delete the offending files themselves.

> I have an entry for Icon? in my gitignore file.

That makes no difference.  A `.gitignore` works on the working directory; these files are inside the repository folder where Git stores its metadata.  `.gitignore` does not apply there.  Git is mistaking them as branch names.

To fix this problem, you may be able to remove the custom icon you gave your folder(s).  But if not, you will need to remove the files from beneath the `.git` folder.  You can do this in Finder (after turning on "Show Hidden Files") or from the command line:

```
rm .git/refs/Icon?
```

**Make sure to backup your repository before attempting this** as changing things in the `.git` folder can corrupt your repository.

Comment: I ran a script that basically put a file in every directory with a directory listing in it. I did this at the root and had to run this to fix it which essentially does the same thing as the above command, but faster if you automated your disaster like I did. 
`find .git/ -iname "my-directory-list.txt" -delete`

Answer (score 0):

I had this:

> warning: ignoring ref with broken name refs/heads/main (DropboxUser's conflicted copy 2023-08-22)

From an accidental Dropbox access. Since the name contained spaces, `git` was busted. I wrapped the name in parentheses and this command worked to remove the duplicate branch:

```
git update-ref -d "refs/heads/main (DropboxUser's conflicted copy 2023-08-22)"
```

Comment: Solves the problem through delete the ref. Just want to point at this fact. 
Solved the problem for me, too since i don't need this refs.