# warning: ignoring broken ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD

Tags: git, bash

Since a few days ago, every time I press <kbd>tab</kbd> key to complete branch names in bash I see the message:

> warning: ignoring broken ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD warning: ignoring broken ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD

For example, this is what I see when I have a branch called feature/foo and I press <kbd>tab</kbd>:

```
git checkout f

$ git checkout fwarning: ignoring broken ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
eature/
```

Comment: These could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990734/how-to-fix-warning-ignoring-ref-with-broken-name-in-git (or) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894135/removing-broken-names-in-git-dropbox-conflicted-copy

Comment: Do you have a branch called "origin/HEAD"?, try `git fetch` and then `git branch -r`. It maybe that you need to do some clean up. If this is the cases I can post up some clean-up functions... (like `git fetch -p` which removes local refs that have been removed on the remote).

Answer (score 248, accepted):

I encountered this recently when someone on my team deleted our old development branch from the remote. I ran this command to check the status of HEAD:

```
$ git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
refs/remotes/origin/old_dev
```

This command output the name of the old development branch, which no longer exists.

I fixed the warnings using this:

```
$ git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin/new_dev
```

(Where "new_dev" is a branch name. Replace it with the name of the branch you want HEAD to point to.)

Comment: Thanks! I had the same issue when I deleted the `master` branch in my repo.

Comment: I think a lot of people are going to find this around now with the trend to switch from master to main.  Thanks!

Answer (score 153):

This is a simpler solution than symbolic-ref.

---

Since **you may have excluded** the branch that **origin/HEAD** was initially pointed to.

**1. List your remote branches with:**

```
git branch -r
```

**2. If it doesn't show in the results:**

```
origin/HEAD -> origin/(something)
```

**3. Just point it again with:**

```
git remote set-head origin master
```

where "master" is the name of your primary (head) branch.

---

Running `git branch -r` again now shows `origin/HEAD -> origin/(something)` and the warning goes away.

Comment: This answer was the easiest for me to understand and digest and worked a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a rule (of thumb) regarding what `HEAD` should point to? Put another way, when would `HEAD` not point to `master`?

Comment: @tim.rohrer, the rule of thumb is to choose your most important branch to be `HEAD`. The branch that you, your team and collaborators must see first when cloning and, *most probably*, the branch from where new production releases comes from.

Comment: Mmmm, okay. Seems the most important branch for developers would be `develop` but the production releases likely come from `master`. I can do more research, but not sure I see why we have `HEAD`.

Comment: When you clone a repository, your new clone will be pointing to HEAD

Comment: And, if your developers publish on `master` the validated code created on `develop`, and releases are made from `master`, then `master` is your most important branch, and it's interesting that `HEAD` points to it.

Comment: There are many use cases. In open source softwares that maintain more than one version (i.e. 1.0.x, 1.5.x, 2.0.x), it's common to see each important version as a separated branch, where improvements, corrections and additions can be made to a specific version, without compromising the other ones. In this case, `HEAD` normally points to the branch that represents the production branch of the most recent version.

Answer (score 23):

> Just run the command -

```
#replace the <branch name> with your main branch - master, main, etc.    
git remote set-head origin <branch name>
```

> Enjoy!

Comment: Remember, your HEAD might not be called `master`. You must use whatever your most important branch is. e.g. `master`, `main`, `rc` whatever branch you expect a developer to be on.

Answer (score 9):

My solution was to delete the folder/file:

> ./.git/refs/remotes/origin/{branch_name}

Afterwards I was finally able to make a git fetch again.

Comment: Is not a git solution but is a little nice hack. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Easiest way to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Some problems arise after the local master renames main:

- `git fetch`: "fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/master";
- `git branch -u origin/main main`: "error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/main' does not exist";
- `git remote set-head origin main`: "error: Not a valid ref: refs/remotes/origin/main";
- `git push -u origin main`: "error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:/.git'";
- `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/main` or `git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin/main` or `git update-ref refs/heads/main main`,

  - and then `git branch -r`: "warning: ignoring broken ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD";

The solution to this problem:

1. `git remote -v`, **copy git repository url**
2. `git remote rm origin`, remove remote
3. `git remote add origin <REPOSITORY_URL>`, reset remote url
4. `git fetch origin`
5. `git branch -u origin/main main`, reset branch upstream

Comment: If just rename: `git branch -m master main` → `git fetch origin` → `git branch -u origin/main main`

Answer (score 3):

To fix this error, remove the following file YOURPROJECT/.git/refs/remotes/origin/master, and then run git fetch to download it again. It will solve your problem.

Comment: The question is old. I already have a solution but thank you for your time!

Comment: One should not delete files in `.git` manually, as this will often have unintended consequences. Rather, find (and learn) the proper `git` command with the intended effect.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was the file `.git\refs\remotes\origin\master` that got corrupted, maybe since my computer was involuntary disconnected from power a few days ago.

I solved it by replacing the file content with the correct reference, a 40 char hex number that can be found in the file `.git\FETCH_HEAD`.

Comment: I had to do something similar as what you proposed but with destination the file .git/refs/stash that was empty

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the default branch of your remote `origin` doesn't exists anymore.
Fix the default branch of the remote:

- GitHub: https://github.com/USER_OR_ORG/REPOSITORY/settings/branches -> "Default branch"
- Bitbucket Cloud: https://bitbucket.org/USER_OR_ORG/REPOSITORY/admin -> " Main branch"
- Bitbucket Server: http://git.sid.distribution.edf.fr/projects/PROJECT/repos/REPOSITORY/settings -> "Default branch"

Comment: I don't think this works. Changing the main or default branch is what you need to do if you want to delete that remote branch in the first place, but changing this doesn't fix the broken ref.

Answer (score 0):

Like already answered - The warning indicates that the remote branch no longer exists, e.g. when the remote branch is merged+deleted into another branch.

In my case I had to delete my local branch, because it was not longer needed and fixing the broken ref was not possible. Therefore, `git branch -d feature/..` did the job.