# Git repository recovered from dying hard drive

Tags: git

Recently my macbook pro hard drive started to give IO errors and I started to loose the abiblity to accesss data files. I had my code on it, luckily after several copy attempts it appears to have copied project to my backup drive.

I want to check all the project data recovered (git repo) is correct and not corrupt. Can you suggest what should I do to check its integrity ?

**Edit**
I ran the command

```
git fsck
```

But this has given output of atleast 150 lines all containing similar to the one shown below nothing else

```
dangling blob 0ea049081a915adecebfced424ae9bd10ff70075
```

Does it mean the data has been corrupted ?

Thanks,

Comment: Validating data requires knowing something about the data.

Comment: git checksums everything. there should be a "validate this tree" option in there somewhere.

Comment: Dangling objects don't indicate corruption.

Comment: Consider enabling Time Machine to have OS X back up on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run [git-fsck](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#checking-for-corruption). Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545407/recovering-broken-git-repository/1545919#1545919).

Comment: Dangling objects do not necessarily mean there's corruption. It could also be commits of a deliberately deleted branch that were not yet garbage collected. Try `git fsck --no-dangling` to see if you get any other errors.

Comment: --no-dangling does not give any information just says checking obj directories 100% done.

Comment: Reading through [How to fix a broken repository?](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#fix-broken-repo) again which says `Ok, I removed the "dangling commit" messages, because they are just messages about the fact that you probably have rebased etc, so they're not at all interesting.` confirms that ignoring dangling commits is fine. They recommend to use `--full`, however. If you don't see any `broken link` or `missing blob` messages with this you should be fine.